# Webserver firewall iptables settings seem to be blocking more than expected

Tags: debian, iptables, web-hosting

I am trying to allow all incoming connections from my local network, and http/https connections from anywhere while blocking all other traffic.

Here are my current rules:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.0.0/16       anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

From what I understand about iptables this should be working, but for some reason http/https access seems to be blocked from outside the local network.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem. The issue was that traffic from 127.0.0.0.0/8 was blocked (I assume apache does something on the localhost which requires that to be open).

These rules work!

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.0.0/16       anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  127.0.0.0/8          anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```